# JPQL Check greater than less than date today in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

I want to check weather `validTill` date is greater than `today` using JPQL. I know that I can achieve this by following.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.validTill > :today ");
```

and pass the `:today` parameter. **But this is not I wanted.** I want to do this using `@Query` annotation in the `CrudRepository` in Spring.

This is my code segment in the `CrudRepository`

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.validFrom < TODAY")
Iterable<MyEntity> findAllValid();
```

I don't know what I should put at the place `TODAY` to get the today's date. Please help me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found it. it's like this..

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.validFrom < CURRENT_DATE")
Iterable<MyEntity> findAllValid();
```

`CURRENT_DATE` - is evaluated to the current date (a java.sql.Date instance).

`CURRENT_TIME` - is evaluated to the current time (a java.sql.Time instance).

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - is evaluated to the current timestamp, i.e. date and time
(a java.sql.Timestamp instance).

Comment: Is there a solution for `java.time.Instant`?

Comment: For java.time.Instant, you can pass it as parameter, I think

`@Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.validFrom < :date")
Iterable<MyEntity> findAllValid(Instant date);`